# Difference between "it's freezing in here" and ""it's freezing here"

Tags: grammar

I saw the sentence "it's freezing in here" in Cambridge dictionary.
But I learned in the past both "here" and "there" do not accompany preposition.
In this case, I did not think "in" was needed.

"It's freezing here" is grammatically wrong?
And what does "in" mean in this case?

Answer (score 3):

*It's freezing in here* would be said by someone in a closed space - a room, or a house or other building.

The word *here* has several uses, as an adverb, adjective and noun.
In this use, *here* is a noun, meaning *this place*, and it is the object of the preposition *in*.

Someone in a warm place in the winter might say *It's freezing out there*.

The phrase *It's freezing here.* is not specific about where *here* is.

Just *it's freezing*, without a location, might mean that it's cold where the speaker is, or that some object is being frozen.

Comment: Not a suitable question for a site aimed at linguists.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think it is enough to migrate the question, no need to downvote...

Comment: @fev people should vote to migrate and then answer in such obviously basic questions. It's my experience that they don't. // Collins: 'Sheila was in here a minute ago'.

Answer (score 0):

> I learned in the past both "here" and "there" do not accompany preposition.

I have never learned that. Actually, [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/here-and-there) says the opposite:

> We can use *here* and *there* ***after prepositions***:
>
> - Is there a bank ***around here***?
> - It’s cold ***in here***. Shut that door!
> - A: Where shall I put this box of books?
>   B: Oh, put it ***over there***, please, by the bookshelf.

***In here*** could be considered a more specific version of ***here***. It means that *here* is somewhere ***inside***, most commonly inside a confined limited space like a room, group, situation, circle. It can also refer to a wider space when someone feels trapped in that space, even if it is as big as China:

> Get me out of this country, I am dying ***in here***.